# Create 2 array's from one array ecmascript 2015

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have one array and I need to be able to get 2 array's from it. I need those 2 array's for a chart. The charts component needs a labels array and a totals array (for each label).

This is the array I have:

```
const income =  [
    {
      "date": 1482233886000,
      "name": "Company A",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary jan. 2017",
      "amount": 50.6
    },
    {
      "date": 1482406686000,
      "name": "Company B",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary jan. 2017",
      "amount": 40.23
    },
    {
      "date": 1485171486000,
      "name": "Company A",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary feb. 2017",
      "amount": 200.2
    },
    {
      "date": 1485344286000,
      "name": "Company B",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary feb. 2017",
      "amount": 100.4
    },
    {
      "date": 1490655892000,
      "name": "Company A",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary mar. 2017",
      "amount": 20
    },
    {
      "date": 1493335850000,
      "name": "Company A",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary apr. 2017",
      "amount": 15
    },
    {
      "date": 1493335850000,
      "name": "Company B",
      "type": "Salary",
      "description": "Salary apr. 2017",
      "amount": 10
    }
  ];
```

To get the labels I did this to get the unique labels (descriptions):

```
[...new Set(income.map(value => value.description))]
=> ["Salary jan. 2017", "Salary feb. 2017", "Salary mar. 2017", "Salary apr. 2017"]
```

That works, but now I want the total amount of every description eg:

```
//[90.83, 300.6, 20, 25]
```

Can some one please helps me with the last array and in ES6 style if it's possible. I thought to go with reduce, but I couldn't get anywhere with that. So I hope a master can teach me ;D.

Comment: `const amounts = income.map(value => value.amount)`

Comment: The op needs a 'group by' summation not a list of amounts.

Comment: `forEach` and `map` are not "new". They are "old". They are also not ECMAScript 2015, which is ES6. They are ES5.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce into a Map, the resulting keys() and values() will be your arrays, grouped and summed by description.

```js
const income = [{"date": 1482233886000,"name": "Company A","type": "Salary","description": "Salary jan. 2017","amount": 50.6},{"date": 1482406686000,"name": "Company B","type": "Salary","description": "Salary jan. 2017","amount": 40.23},{"date": 1485171486000,"name": "Company A","type": "Salary","description": "Salary feb. 2017","amount": 200.2},{"date": 1485344286000,"name": "Company B","type": "Salary","description": "Salary feb. 2017","amount": 100.4},{"date": 1490655892000,"name": "Company A","type": "Salary","description": "Salary mar. 2017","amount": 20},{"date": 1493335850000,"name": "Company A","type": "Salary","description": "Salary apr. 2017","amount": 15},{"date": 1493335850000,"name": "Company B","type": "Salary","description": "Salary apr. 2017","amount": 10}];

let res = income.reduce((a, b) => {
  a.set(b.description, (a.get(b.description) || 0) + b.amount);
  return a;
}, new Map());

console.log([...res.values()]); // the summed amount
console.log([...res.keys()]); // the description property
```

Edit for your comment

To add an entry to a Map you use set() - in the example above, I'm using the description property as a key and add the amount to that. This part of the code:

```
(a.get(b.description) || 0)
```

basically just checks if the created Map holds a key like the iterated description, and if so, it takes the existing amount to add to that. The `||` short circuits, so if  there's no existing amount (a.get(b.description) is undefined), 0 is taken instead. English is not my first language - here's an easier example of what I mean:

```js
let m = new Map();
m.set("foo", 1);
let a = m.get("foo");
console.log(a); // 1 - obvious
let b = m.get("bar");
console.log(b); // undefined

console.log(b || 0); // 0, as b is undefined, 0 is taken
// in the original answer, this would be the same as 
if (! b) b = 0;
console.log(b); 0

let c = (b || 0) + 1; // 0 + 1 because b is undefined;
console.log("c: ", c);

let d = (a || 0) + 1; // 1 + 1 because a holds 1;
console.log("d:", d);
```

Comment: A Map is just like an Object except that it can have any object (not just strings) as a key, and you use `get` and `set` to, er, get and set members.

Comment: Not the only difference though, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared) @Kinduser

Comment: Thanks, I will read about it tomorrow, because my eyes going to explode after whole day, hihi. Good night (: @Jordan baao

Comment: @baao thanks, can you elaborate a little bit more on the answer. especially this line:  a.set(b.description, (a.get(b.description) || 0) ?

Comment: @AnnaSmother I've added some explanation to the answer. Does this make it clear for you?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

- Filter the `income` variable to get rid of the duplicate descriptions
- Take every element of the filtered array and iterate over the `income` array to get the entries with the same `description` value and then sum up their `amount` property
- Push the total amount of every element into newly made `arr` array.

```js
const income=[{date:1482233886e3,name:"Company A",type:"Salary",description:"Salary jan. 2017",amount:50.6},{date:1482406686e3,name:"Company B",type:"Salary",description:"Salary jan. 2017",amount:40.23},{date:1485171486e3,name:"Company A",type:"Salary",description:"Salary feb. 2017",amount:200.2},{date:1485344286e3,name:"Company B",type:"Salary",description:"Salary feb. 2017",amount:100.4},{date:1490655892e3,name:"Company A",type:"Salary",description:"Salary mar. 2017",amount:20},{date:149333585e4,name:"Company A",type:"Salary",description:"Salary apr. 2017",amount:15},{date:149333585e4,name:"Company B",type:"Salary",description:"Salary apr. 2017",amount:10}];

var arr = [];
var sorted = [...new Set(income.map(value => value.description))];
sorted.forEach(function(v){
  var obj = {};
  var sum = 0;
  income.forEach(function(c){
    if (c.description == v){
      sum += c.amount;
    }
  });
  obj[v] = sum;
  arr.push(obj);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I can't run it atm, but if I understand correctly, the description is the key and the amount is the value?

Comment: @AnnaSmother Exactly.